# Welches Wörterbuch kann mir helfen, damit ich Goethes "Faust" verstehe?

Tags: literature

Ich bin gerade dabei, den ersten Teil des Werkes zu lesen. Allerdings habe ich schon mit "Nathan der Weise" und "Die Räuber" die Erfahrung gemacht, dass viele Wörter in einer abgewandelten Form vorkommen oder so gut wie keine Verwendung finden.

Da hilft z. B. der Duden oder Langenscheidt nicht gut, da diese die gegenwärtige Sprache wiederspiegeln.

**Welches Wörterbuch kann mir bei diesem Werk behilflich sein?**

Comment: Wenn es dir um eine Übersetzung ins Englische geht, solltest du es mal Linguee versuchen. Es gibt von Faust auch jede Menge Sekundärliteratur und bestimmt auch Ausgaben mit Anmerkungen. Das ist vielleicht hilfreicher, als ein einfaches Wörterbuch.

Comment: @clemens Am hilfreichsten wäre mir eine Erklärung auf Deutsch. Zur Not würde mir auch eine Erklärung auf Englisch genügen.

Comment: Was meinst du mit "der Duden"? - Wenn du den Rechtschreib-Duden meinst, okay. Aber hast du es probiert mit Dudens dickem Universalwörterbuch?

Comment: ... vielleicht ist das Problem, wie schon Clemens wohl andeutet, eher, dass so ein Werk wie Faust ja nicht aus den Worten allein heraus zu verstehen ist. Man braucht jede Menge kulturgeschichtlichen Kontext im Hinterkopf, um dem Autor recht folgen zu können...

Comment: Es gibt Ausgaben für den Faust mit Anmerkungen (z.B. Reclam XL). Die sind in der Regel auf dem Niveau von Oberstufenschülern, weil das Werk unter Anderem zum Abiturstoff gehört. Solche Ausgaben sind wahrscheinlich hilfreicher als ein Wörterbuch, da die Begriffe im Kontext erklärt werden. Ansonsten finde ich den Faust (zumindest den ersten Teil) im Vergleich zu anderen Klassikern recht flüssig lesbar.

Comment: Gegebenenfalls ist auch Teil des Problems, dass viele ältere grammatikalische Formen (Dativ-e) verwendet werden, und des Öfteren Wörter abgekürzt werden (nicht unbedingt intuitiv!), damit das Versmaß aufgeht …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es gibt Ausgaben für den Faust, wie für viele andere Klassiker auch, mit Anmerkungen (z.B. Reclam XL). Die sind in der Regel auf dem Niveau von Oberstufenschülern, weil das Werk unter Anderem zum Abiturstoff gehört.

Solche Ausgaben sind wahrscheinlich hilfreicher als ein Wörterbuch, da die Begriffe im Kontext erklärt werden. Ansonsten finde ich den Faust (zumindest den ersten Teil) im Vergleich zu anderen Klassikern recht flüssig lesbar.

Answer (score 0):

Ich weiß dass schon eine Antwort gibts aber, wenn du eine neue Wörterbuch suchts könntest du mit [Leo](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/) versuchen.